# jQuery multiple selectors order with "this"

Tags: jquery, this

The order of 'i' and 'this' matters. The first one, the icon was added behind the button. The second one, the icon was added before the button. Why is that?

example 1:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('i', this).removeClass().addClass("icon-down");
})
```

example 2:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this, 'i').removeClass().addClass("icon-down");
})
```

Comment: The way you are using it is [`jQuery(selector, [context])`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1), rather than `jQuery("selector, selector")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that these two forms you are using will generate different results.

```
$('i', this)
```

This form will find any `<i>` elements that are children of the element pointed to by `this`.  it is structurally equivalent to `$(this).find('i')` which is my preferred way to write it because I think it's more readable.

From the jQuery doc, this form is documented as `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`.

---

Your other form:

```
$(this, 'i')
```

is not really a directly supported option for the jQuery function as there are not documented options that take `(element, string)`.   I will check the jQuery code, but this is likely just going to be interpreted as the `$(element)` form and thus will just be `$(this)` with the second argument getting ignored.  This option is documented as `jQuery( element )`.  The second argument is ignored if the first argument is a DOM element.

So, the first option finds child `<i>` elements.  The second option just operates on the button itself.

**EDIT:** In looking at the jQuery source code, I've verified that `$(this, 'i')` is treated the same as `$(this)`.  In fact, this is the operative part of the jQuery function:

```
init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
    if ( typeof selector === "string" ) {
        // handle selector string here    
        // ...

    // HANDLE: $(DOMElement)
    } else if ( selector.nodeType ) {
        this.context = this[0] = selector;
        this.length = 1;
        return this;
    }
```